# How to detect jagged rows in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a data issue where we'd like to take a backup of a particular Kind and determine which rows are "jagged", so effectively I'm trying to detect which rows are missing a certain column (meaning the field does not exist on that row, which I'm distinguishing from being null).  Is there a way to do this in BigQuery?

Comment: IS NULL language construct doesn't help you?

Comment: My concern is that "IS NULL" doesn't address the lack of field, but instead would return rows that do have that field with the value NULL.

Comment: So you are trying to load data without defining columns for them?

Comment: Well the concern is that some entities were created with that field defined and data in that field, and some entities were created without any reference to that field (which I would consider different from just nulling out that field).  Perhaps there is no difference in BigQuery and what I'm describing is impossible?

Comment: Post examples of such entities so we can understand better the problem. You can edit your original questions to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs:

> **configuration.load.allowJaggedRows**    *boolean*   [Optional] Accept rows
>   that are missing trailing optional columns. The missing values are
>   treated as nulls. Default is false which treats short rows as errors.
>   Only applicable to CSV, ignored for other formats.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs

This means missing values from jagged rows will be treated as null. You might need to try a different approach if preserving these values is important, like ingesting the whole row and parsing inside BigQuery - when possible.